# How to remove #N/A from cells running a macro? - vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a new entry of coding.
I've created a code for a macro and I have problems with #N/A
how can I remove them? please help me!
here's my code:

```
ProdInStruct_New = .Range(.Range(lblRange_EditStructure_Prod).Offset(1, 0), .Range(lblRange_EditStructure_Prod).Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Value
ProdInStruct_New = Application.Transpose(ProdInStruct_New)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be better to more specific in order to get help quicker. Where are these #N/As? Are you saying that they are caused by your code? Can you post sample data so we can see what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

After setting the range as a variable, it would be better to determine whether there is an error in the range object, empty the value, and then retrieve it as an array.

```
Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range

Set rngDB = .Range(.Range(lblRange_EditStructure_Prod).Offset(1, 0), .Range(lblRange_EditStructure_Prod).Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))

For Each rng In rngDB
    If IsError(rng) Then
        rng.Value = Empty
    End If
Next rng

ProdInStruct_New = rngDB
ProdInStruct_New = Application.Transpose(ProdInStruct_New)
```

If you don't want to use loop statements, you can use specialcells.

```
Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
Dim rngErr As Range
Set rngDB = .Range(.Range(lblRange_EditStructure_Prod).Offset(1, 0), .Range(lblRange_EditStructure_Prod).Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))

On Error Resume Next
Set rngErr = rngDB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)
rngErr = Empty

ProdInStruct_New = rngDB
ProdInStruct_New = Application.Transpose(ProdInStruct_New)
```

To correct the error in the array itself

```
ProdInStruct_New = .Range(.Range(lblRange_EditStructure_Prod).Offset(1, 0), .Range(lblRange_EditStructure_Prod).Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))

For i = 1 To UBound(ProdInStruct_New, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(ProdInStruct_New, 2)
        If IsError(ProdInStruct_New(i, j)) Then
           ProdInStruct_New(i, j) = Empty
        End If
    Next j
Next i

ProdInStruct_New = Application.Transpose(ProdInStruct_New)
```